# Display photos in time slider

Tags: arcscene, fly-through, photos, timeslider

I have a shapefile of points with geotagged photos attached through the Photos toolset, they correspond to a line shapefile that documents a trail taken while hiking. I am looking to create a video of the progress through the trail with the photos displaying at the relevant times (both data sets are time-enabled).

I have experience with the time slider tool but cannot get the photos to display when the points they are attached to are in the time frame, and am completely unexperienced with ArcScene and the Fly tool. I am going to start fumbling around with the fly tool now, but if anyone has any experience with this I would appreciate tips.
Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention, my data is not 3D, so I have no real preference for the time slider or fly tool, just something that works.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a similar thing to browse geotagged photos on a map (plus video on top). It's a lightweight alternative to existing ArcGis functions.

You can see it in action here: http://apps.vidmap.de/alaska

Comment: Looks interesting, is this app available?